# Spring SOAP ERROR: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory]

Tags: java, spring, soap

i try to create soap service with java 11 and spring. But when I try to use it, connect to http://localhost:8080/ws/countries.wsdl , I have this stack trase:

> 2021-05-04 12:53:11.624 ERROR 22232 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]
> o.s.w.t.http.MessageDispatcherServlet    : Context initialization
> failed
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could
> not initialize WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter; nested
> exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException:
> Failed to instantiate
> [org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory]:
> Unresolvable class definition; nested exception is
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/soap/MessageFactory     at
> org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet.initMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter(MessageDispatcherServlet.java:391)
> ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.10.RELEASE.jar:na]   at
> org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet.initStrategies(MessageDispatcherServlet.java:369)
> ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.10.RELEASE.jar:na]   at
> org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet.onRefresh(MessageDispatcherServlet.java:301)
> ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.10.RELEASE.jar:na]   at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:599)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]  at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:530)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]  at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:170)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]  at
> javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:4.0.FR]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1134)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:777)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]    at
> org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]    at
> org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]    at
> org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]    at
> org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]    at
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]    at
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]    at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]    at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]    at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
> ~[na:na]  at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]    at
> java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na] Caused by:
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate [org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory]:
> Unresolvable class definition; nested exception is
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/soap/MessageFactory     at
> org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:157)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]   at
> org.springframework.ws.support.DefaultStrategiesHelper.instantiateBean(DefaultStrategiesHelper.java:152)
> ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.10.RELEASE.jar:na]   at
> org.springframework.ws.support.DefaultStrategiesHelper.getDefaultStrategies(DefaultStrategiesHelper.java:134)
> ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.10.RELEASE.jar:na]   at
> org.springframework.ws.support.DefaultStrategiesHelper.getDefaultStrategy(DefaultStrategiesHelper.java:219)
> ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.10.RELEASE.jar:na]   at
> org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet.initWebServiceMessageFactory(MessageDispatcherServlet.java:402)
> ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.10.RELEASE.jar:na]   at
> org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet.initMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter(MessageDispatcherServlet.java:387)
> ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.10.RELEASE.jar:na]   ... 24 common frames omitted
> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> javax/xml/soap/MessageFactory     at
> java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3215)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3420) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2631)
> ~[na:na]  at
> org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]   ... 29 common frames omitted Caused
> by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
> ~[na:na]  ... 34 common frames omitted

I use maven with this dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.ws-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.soap</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.soap-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.jws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.jws-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj</groupId>
            <artifactId>saaj-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jaxen</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxen</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>maven-cobertura-plugin</artifactId>
                    <groupId>maven-plugins</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>maven-findbugs-plugin</artifactId>
                    <groupId>maven-plugins</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
                    <groupId>xalan</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
                    <groupId>xerces</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>xalan</groupId>
            <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                    <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.1</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                    <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

I literraly add all what i can and don't know what to do. Thank you

Comment: Did you solve this one?
I have the same error with java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory and nothing I found with importing saaj-api, javax.xml.soap-api or similar stuff didn't helped.